# some examples of a Banach algebra with given conditions

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, banach-algebras

What are some examples of Banach algerba $A$ satsifying the following two conditions?

$1$. $A$ does not have an approximate idebtity.

$2$. $A^2=A$. That is, for any $a\in A$, there exist some $b,c\in A$ such that $a=bc$.

A direct application of the Cohen factorization theorem shows that if $A$ has a bounded approximate identity, then $2$ holds.

Any help would be appreciated.